# Ruby 2.7 specific warning not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deprecation-warning

We want to update our codebase to Ruby 3 and one of the biggest breaking change is the mix of keyword arguments with arguments in methods. This warning should show up

```rb
warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
```

But I've noticed when running a simple script, it just doesn't appear

```rb
# script.rb
def my_method(argument, other:)
  puts "hello"
end

options = { other: "medium" }
argument = true

my_method(argument, options)

$ rvm use 2.7.5
$ ruby script.rb
hello

$ rvm use 3.0.1
$ ruby script.rb
script.rb:1:in `my_method': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1; required keyword: other) (ArgumentError)
    from script.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

It breaks as planned in Ruby 3, but doesn't show anything in the previous versions.

This behavior is the same in production for us, I couldn't spot one occurrence anywhere. I've used `RUBYOPT='-W:deprecated'` or even `$VERBOSE = true` that successfully list several other deprecation warnings except this one.

After looking around, it doesn't seem other people have this problem. Is there something I am missing here? Is there an option in Ruby? Using other versions of Ruby like 2.7.2 renders the same.

Another detail, we use Ruby on Rails ton run everything, but I believe the problem is within Ruby itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've discovered a few things. First of all, Ruby 2.7.2 and later don't show warnings by default which would explain the difference of behavior in my tests. To activate them you have to use `RUBYOPT`

```sh
# Ruby 2.7.5
$ RUBYOPT='-W:deprecated' ruby script.rb
script.rb:8: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
script.rb:1: warning: The called method `my_method' is defined here
hello
```

Another point is that the `$VERBOSE = true` you can set later on doesn't work either to show this warning. I'm not sure exactly why, but only `RUBYOPT` would do the job for this specific problem.

Finally, I also had used wrongly the `RUBYOPT` option when starting my Rails server locally thus not seeing it working.

I hope it helps.

Comment: "Ruby 2.7.2 and later don't show warnings by default " – No version of Ruby has ever shown warnings by default. In fact, almost no language implementation I know of shows warnings by default.

Comment: you should also fix your code. don't just ignore warnings.

Comment: @JörgWMittag https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2020/10/02/ruby-2-7-2-released/ they say here something was turned off though

Comment: @Jad of course my plan is to fix the whole codebase thanks to those warnings

Comment: Just a note that after Ruby 2.7.2 switched to having deprecation warnings off by default, Minitest was updated to set `Warning[:deprecated] = true` [here](https://github.com/minitest/minitest/pull/871).  So far RSpec has chosen [not to make a similar change](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/2867).